# CSS flow justified text around an image

Tags: css

tring to flow text around an image:

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <span id="photo"><img src="photo.png"</span>
  <span id="text">Lorem Ipsum, blah, blah, blah ...</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#photo {float:left;margin:0px 8px 5px 0px;}
#text {text-align:justify;}**
```

The text flows around the image, but it is not justified (alignment is left). If I float the text element left, then the alignment is correct (justified, as I want), but then the text does not flow around the image, rather it flows below the image - how can I fix this?

Comment: unclosed tag: `<img src="photo.png"</span>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `text-align` property actually belongs on the enclosing block element not the inline element. So move it to the enclosing block:

```
div { text-align: justify; }
```

See [16.2 Alignment: the 'text-align' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#alignment-prop) of the [Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 1 (CSS 2.1) Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/):

> This property describes how *inline
>   content of a block is aligned*. Values
>   have the following meanings:

(emphasis added)

Comment: Heheh, that worked. Thanks very much. What is the rule that specifies this behaviour? (So I can read it up and understand the reason for this behaviour ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to either take the image out of the span, or float the span left.